# Circular CaptureElement camera stream in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-10, uwp

Wherever you look in Windows 10, there are circles. It's fairly easy to make images circular, but camera is a bit different. Is there a simple XAML way to clip the camera stream in a CaptureElement to make it a circle?

I tried putting it in a border, but CaptureElement doesn't care about its borders. I also tried using the Clip property, but it can only clip to RectangleGeometry.
One way would certainly be to grab CaptureElement frames, transforming them to images (frame by frame) and applying to Image element, and then clipping the image, but it seems like that would have awful performance.

Is there something in the framework to make this really simple, but I'm not seeing it?

Comment: The only way I see is using Win2D but I cannot instantiate to transparent the video, for instance:

Win2D.uap -DisplacementEffect.cs -  ProcessFrame(ProcessVideoFrameContext context).

I have tested set the CanvasAlphaMode, in the constructors of CanvasBitmap and CanvasRenderTarget and also 

ds.Clear(Colors.Transparent);
//ds.DrawImage(dispMap, -25f, -25f);
ds.DrawCircle(new Vector2(100, 100), 100, Colors.Red);

(that works transparent in other cases but video who knows).

I have tweeted to the Win2D team, let's see with their knowledge if it can be achieved

Answer (score 2):

Well after seeing that might be the background is always black of the Canvas DirectX the only way I see is:

1.- Clip a rectangle with an ellipse in Inkscape for instance.

2.- Copy to Expression Design and Ctrl-Shift-C (to copy XAML)

3.- Place inside a ViewBox only the path generated

```
 <Grid  Width="300" Height="300">
            <CaptureElement Name="PreviewControl" Stretch="Uniform" Width="280" Height="280" />
            <Viewbox Width="280" Height="280">
                <Path Width="813.701" Height="813.701" Canvas.Left="-33.3503" Canvas.Top="-45.3503" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF800080" Data="F1 M -33.3503,-45.3503L -33.3503,768.35L 780.35,768.35L 780.35,-45.3503L -33.3503,-45.3503 Z M 373.54,158.095C 485.863,158.095 576.985,249.137 576.985,361.54C 576.985,473.863 485.863,564.985 373.54,564.985C 261.137,564.985 170.095,473.863 170.095,361.54C 170.095,249.137 261.137,158.095 373.54,158.095 Z "/>
            </Viewbox>
        </Grid>
```

[image]

With that you can place an image in the path or a solid color, that's the only way I see to do it. Hope it helps